# Nested collection-Form, append to nearest class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello i have been trying to make a dynamic collection that i can post to the server, after some struggeling i found this guide; 
http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3
Great written but i havent got it to work for my needs.
Everything works fine exept one "little" annoying thing.

First some information about what im trying to achive;

My classes looks like this; 
Qpack has a list of questions
question has a list alternatives

The interface that i have created looks like this;

[image: Dynamic interface, collection of collections]

And this is the markup.
[image: Markup]

The "add Question"-button works great and the markup match, The thing that dosent work is that wen i click on "Add Alternative" it is always being added to the first question. But the markup is fine as seen in the second picture.

The function responsible for the append looks like this;

```
function addNestedForm(container, counter, ticks, content) {
    var nextIndex = $(container + " " + counter).length;
    //var nextIndex = $(counter).length; // Orginal
    var pattern = new RegExp(ticks, "gi");
    content = content.replace(pattern, nextIndex);
    $(container).append(content);
    resetValidation();
}
```

[image]

I want to append to the most relative "alternatives" but it seems that it always goes for the first, any idea how to get it to understand the "nearest" alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a jQuery selector specifies an ID (`#`) and there are multiple IDs in the Html document that have that Id jQuery will always return the first.

You must have a way to specify the "Alternatives" uniquely throughout your page.

Alternatively (pun intended) you can create a new css class, replace

```
<div id="alternative" ...
```

with

```
<div class="alternative-container" ...
```

Then on your action of "Add Alternative" you can

```
var container = $(this).parents('div.alternative-container:first');
```